# C# Syntax for discard variable and syntax for chaining

Tags: c#

I have came across the following code:

```
    EnsureGraphForAppOnlyAuth();
    _ = _appClient ??
        throw new System.NullReferenceException("Graph has not been initialized for app-only auth");
```

I understand if _appClient is null, it will throw an exception. (1)My question is what is `_ =`?  (2)What's it called so I can look it up in a reference?

Next, in continuation of the code, I have this

```
    return _appClient.Groups
      .Request()
      .Select(u => new
      {
        u.DisplayName,
        u.Id
      })
      // Get at most 25 results
      .Top(25)
      // Sort by display name
      .OrderBy("DisplayName")
      .GetAsync();
```

(3)Is this chaining?

```
.Groups
.Request()
.Select()
.OrderBy()
.GetAsync()
```

Doesn't each function depend on the return value of the prior function?  If so, there's no error checking or checking the return value prior to calling the next function?  What happen if these where all async?

Also, if I want to write a class and its function so a client can do the same thing, (4) do I have to do anything special when designing the class except of each function return a value?

Comment: The underscore (treated as italic formatting because it's not formatted as code in the paragraph, so it's not shown) is a discard. The expression on the right side of the `=` is not a valid statement on its own, but if it's evaluated and assigned to nothing (discarded), it becomes valid. I consider this a ridiculous way of avoiding a simple `if` statement to do a `null` check.

Comment: A better question would be to ask what `_` is. It's a discard to indicate that you don't care about the right-hand side of the assignment.

Comment: You shouldn't really need error checking in a linq chain as long as you start out with a non-null collection/type. Some methods can cause issues like calling `First` on an empty but there are alternatives like `FirstOrDefault`. And because this example is using the graph api client (?), it's good to go (code-wise) assuming your client is configured and can auth with the api correctly.

Comment: As a side note, you never throw `NullReferenceException` directly. Throw `ArgumentNullException` if it's a parameter or, as in your case, `InvalidOperationException` because the graph has not been initialized yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `_` is a valid variable name in C#.  Usually, developers use it as a placeholder to denote that 'this is required for the syntax to be valid, but I don't intend to use it'
2. Apparently it is called a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards).  I didn't know that it had a real name.
3. Yes, that's using a fluent API style to chain methods together.  Each method uses the return value of the previous method as its parameter.
4. Take a look at how the [LINQ library](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq) is set up.  You'll want to use extension methods similarly